# Problems on my Media-Queries Positioning for Hover Buttons

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, tablet

I finished my coding for all Smartphone Devices and now I started on the Tablets but soon on this Mission I have a problem because im not sure how to fix this.

This is how my "Section Skills" looks like for mobile:
[My section on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnJFK.png)

On tablet i want 3 in each row and not 2 but Im not able to make this and dont know why.

```css
.Skills{
 background-color:#262626; 
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}


.Skills p:nth-child(1){
 padding-top: 54px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:900;
 letter-spacing: 15px;
 color:#fff;
}

.Skills p:nth-child(2){
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:900;
 letter-spacing: 15px;
 color:#fff;
}

.Skills p:nth-child(3){
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#fff;
}

.Skills img:nth-child(4){
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-left: 51px;
}

section {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Programme {
 text-align:center;
 color:#ffffff;
    padding: 20px 0 0 49px;

}

section .Programme:nth-child(2),section .Programme:nth-child(4),section .Programme:nth-child(6),section .Programme:nth-child(8) {
    padding: 20px 49px 0 0;
}

.Programme img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
 transition: filter 1s ease;
    transition : -webkit-filter 1000ms linear;
    width: 102px;
}

.Programme img:hover {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
 transition: filter 1s ease;
    transition : -webkit-filter 1000ms linear
}

h3{
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
 font-weight:700;
}

h4 {
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<article class="Skills">
        <p>MEINE</p>
        <p>SKILLS</p>
        <p>DAS IST MEIN KÖNNEN</p>
        <img src="images/Strich_320.jpg" alt=""/>

        <section>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/Photoshop.png"/>
                <h3>PHOTOSHOP</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/Illustrator.png"/>
                <h3>ILLUSTRATOR</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/InDesign.png"/>
                <h3>INDESIGN</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/Dreamweaver.png"/>
                <h3>DREAMWEAVER</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/AfterEffects.png"/>
                <h3>AFTEREFFECTS</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/PremierePro.png"/>
                <h3>PREMIERE PRO</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/SonyVegas.png"/>
                <h3>SONY VEGAS</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="Programme">
                <img src="images/Cinema4D.png"/>
                <h3>CINEMA4D</h3>
                <h4>Experte, 5 Jahre</h4>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
```

Comment: where is your media-query?

Comment: @NitinDhomse The media-query is the original css code above

Comment: This is not a media-query, its simple css code

Comment: @NitinDhomse no its my media query code becaue above everything is this

/* ----------- iPad mini,1 and 2 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@ media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

Comment: Ohh ok, but its not understandable that which css block is  of which media query you tried so far.

Comment: @NitinDhomse The Block of "Programme" is where the images are and everytime I tryed to set 3 in a row its not working

Comment: In your `@media` rule, do you have a space between `@` and `media`?

Comment: @Rounin the query is working but the part of making it 3 instead of 2 in a row is not working thats the Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell, but it sounds very much like one of the parent containers (either the `section` or the `article`) is too narrow and that once the horizontal `padding` is factored in, the `.programme divs` are too wide to fit 3 in a row.

Try:

```
.programme {
max-width: 20%;
}
```